# Как данные из базы Mysql вставить в график Highcharts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Как вывести данные из таблицы базы данных в график на *js*?

Если я не ошибаюсь, нужно сделать три поля `id, name, click`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chart` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `click` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Дамп данных таблицы `chart`

```
INSERT INTO `chart` (`id`, `name`, `click`) VALUES
(1, 'Jan', 79),
(2, 'Feb', 120),
(3, 'Mar', 269),
(4, 'Apr', 138),
(5, 'May', 472),
(6, 'Jun', 258),
(7, 'Jul', 182),
(8, 'Aug', 372),
(9, 'Sep', 371),
(10, 'Oct', 233),
(11, 'Nov', 273),
(12, 'Dec', 139);
```

[**График** на *Highcharts*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyKzpZ?editors=101)

Данные нужно вставить в два массива `categories` и `data`

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

только не знаю как сделать запрос и вставить данные в скрипт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/boris_U/rry2125v/ - здесь пример как получить данные от базы данных.

```
$.get("http://test.controlcash.ru/get.php", function(resp){
  for (i=0; i<resp.length; i++) {
    cats.push(resp[i].x); 
    data.push(resp[i].y); 
  }
}).done(function() {
   chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(cats);
   chart.series[0].setData(data);        
})
```

Там есть ajax-обращение к php-скрипту, которые возвращает выборку из mysql.

get.php:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_pass", "db_name");
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "select name, click from chart")) {
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
        $array[]=array("x"=>$obj->name, "y"=>(int)$obj->click);
    }
    /* очищаем результирующий набор */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($db);

$ar_js = json_encode($array);
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2017 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

echo $ar_js;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня только небольшой вопрос как составлен запрос и сам код ( get.php )

Comment: @Muson: Запрос? ну это зависит от структуры вашей таблицы и вообще от логики вашего приложения. Как делать выборки из MySQL средствами PHP - можно найти и на этом сайте и в официальной документации по PHP (http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Не могу вставить данные из get.php в скрипт , я в свой вопрос вставил структуру таблицы базы данных, простые запросы я умею делать, только не могу понять, как сделана выборка данных в get.php ?

Comment: @Muson: обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо  за ответ